# Coding user hierachy java

Tags: java, security, design-patterns

I am designing some software that contains different users with different privileges, these are not related to the underlying os they are within my program.

Is there a design pattern for this sort of thing?

Ideally i would like it possible to create users with multiple groups as you can in unix.
For example 
user A is in user group A and user group C
user B is in user group A and user group B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to have a database of all possible privileges and then assign appropriate privileges to users. Before you write any action that requires a privilege, have a handy method something like `boolean isAuthorized(User user, PrivilegeType privilege)` to test.

There are many authentication and authorization frameworks in Java. I personally prefer [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html) for it's simplicity and small learning curve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for that, i am not sure why it didnt cross my mind to use a database.... not enought coffee i think!